# Saving HBase table data in a particular HDFS location

Tags: hive, hbase

On Hive table, I can create external table which save data on a particular HDFS location. I want to do the similar thing on HBase so HBase table data can be saved on an external HDFS location. Is that possible to do this on HBase similar to Hive? I want to know what is default path on HDFS where HBase table data are saved to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, HBase does not give you the same kind of external table ability that Hive does.

HBase is designed differently than Hive, and uses different methods and software to read and write data.  Whereas Hive traditionally uses MapReduce or Tez to interact with data in HDFS, like your external tables, HBase uses its collection of RegionServer processes running on the cluster. By design, the RegionServers share a directory tree in HDFS in which they operate on files.

There is a property called `hbase.rootdir` in the `hbase-site.xml` configuration file which sets the root path in HDFS for all HBase data files.  That property looks like this:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://hostname:8020/hbase</value>
</property>
```

(It's not necessary to create this directory manually, HBase does it. If this parameter is not set, then by default all data will go into a subdirectory of `hbase.tmp.dir`, which is usually /tmp .)

But again, this config setting is **not** analogous to creating an external table in Hive. This HDFS path is shared by all RegionServers when persisting data to disk. It's not a directory which you, the user, interact with directly when reading and writing data.